# react-native command is not recognized yet after installing react-native globally

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to set up react-native in a new system, have followed the documentation exactly as it is written but when I try hitting react-native run-android it says

Command `react-native` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

I have installed react native globally, yet I receive this error

Could anyone let me know how to resolve this?

the logs are follows:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'exec',
0 verbose cli   '--',
0 verbose cli   'react-native',
0 verbose cli   'react-native',
0 verbose cli   'run-android'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.5.1
2 info using node@v15.8.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:C:\sheolife-rn\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\info\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\info\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 9ms
19 verbose npm-session e63e802460c0c690
20 timing npm:load Completed in 22ms
21 timing command:exec Completed in 226ms
22 verbose stack Error: command failed
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20)
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
23 verbose pkgid sheolife@0.0.1
24 verbose cwd C:\sheolife-rn
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "react-native" "react-native" "run-android"
27 verbose node v15.8.0
28 verbose npm  v7.5.1
29 error code 1
30 error path C:\sheolife-rn
31 error command failed
32 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native react-native run-android
33 verbose exit 1
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sheolife",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start-web": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test-web": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject-web": "react-scripts eject",
    "prettier": "prettier --write './src'",
    "yarn-ios": "yarn ios --simulator `iPhone 6s` --verbose",
    "clear-modules": "rm -rf node_modules; rm -f package-lock.json; rm -f yarn.lock"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "modal-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-art": "^16.5.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.9.0",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.3",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-custom-datetimepicker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-debugger": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.3",
    "react-native-pie": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-progress-bar-animated": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.2.8",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-speedometer-chart": "^0.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.14.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.0",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-modal": "^2.0.0-rc3",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "victory-native": "^35.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.63.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "homepage": "http://parentlane.com/babyapp/"
}
```

Comment: react-native run-android

Comment: have added, could you please check

Comment: I have updated my answer, try those commands

Answer (score 0):

try the following,

Open terminal one and run these command,

```
npx react-native start
```

Open terminal two and run these command,

```
npx react-native run-android
```

EDIT:
Open terminal one and run these command,

```
npm start
```

Open terminal two and run these command,

```
npm android
```

Comment: Try reinstalling Node and React Native. restart your pc